# Set different text/value for dropdown with Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui

I would like to set different text / value for a dropdown I have with AngularJS. Currently both the text and the value are same by using this syntax:

```
<select name="flightNum" class="form-control" ng-model="model.flight"
       ng-options="v.Value as v.Text for v in flights" required></select>
```

I tried this approach:

```
<select name="flightNum" class="form-control" ng-model="model.flight" 
          ng-options="v.Value as v.Text for v in flights" required>
    <option ng-repeat="v in flights" value="{{v.Value}}"> {{v.Text}}</option>
</select>
```

But I've got the same text/value combination. What do I need to change to make this work with AngularJS?

Comment: please see here http://jsbin.com/coculu/1/edit seems to be fine your fist option

Comment: @sylwester in the example you have, if you inspect the element you'll see that the value is 0 and 1 for the dropdown items http://gyazo.com/06a5627b8b1ce76f95b1ad918cecb0de

Comment: you don't have to worry about that please see http://jsbin.com/coculu/2/edit model.flight is binding to proper value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your $scope.flights is setup properly, the first syntax you showed should work. I've setup a plunker to show this in action at http://plnkr.co/edit/PIXZZO81aQKj4kmngoXy?p=preview

It has the following data structure for $scope.flights:

```
  $scope.flights = [{
    value: 'val1',
    text: 'text1'
  }, {
    value: 'val2',
    text: 'text2'
  }, {
    value: 'val3',
    text: 'text3 '
  }]
```

Then, the select can be written essentially as you have it (i used lowercase value and text on accident, but just make sure it matches between the controller and the html):

```
<select name="flightNum" class="form-control" ng-model="model.flight" ng-options="v.value as v.text for v in flights" required></select>
```

With this setup, the dropdown is populated with the values contained in the "text" fields, but selecting something sets the "value" into the model.flight variable. You can see this in the Plunker mentioned above.

Is this the behavior you're wanting? If not, what is happening that is different/unexpected?

Answer (score 1):

you need to add track by in the ng-options

```
<select name="flightNum" class="form-control" ng-model="model.flight"
       ng-options="v.Value as v.Text for v in flights track by v.Value" required>
</select>
```

and that's it.

Comment: Thanks!  I had spent too much time trying to figure this out.  Appreciate the answer.

Comment: glad that this helped you.